# Position absolute wont get relative to parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, position, css-position

I have put my code into codepen to easy display my problem :

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wrVMPy

```
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="front">
                                    <h1>03</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="back">
                                    <p>test</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

(needed to be able to post codepen link for some reason)
```

So, my problem is that the back of the "card", which has position absolute, wont display relative to my viewport. it locks to the bootstrap column instead. i want the red box to always show up right in the middle of the screen when the "card" is clicked but it seems impossible.

Not even position fixed takes it out from the flow and adjust it relative to the main div or viewport.

And also with a z-index of 99 it still doesn't go over the rest of the elements.

I would be too grateful if anyone has an solution to this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: "needed to be able to post codepen link for some reason" - Stack Overflow tells you exactly why that is, but you chose to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `position: absolute` positions the element relative to the first non-static positioned element. In order to make it positioned relative to the viewport you need to use `position: fixed` instead.

Comment: but if you try using position: fixed in my code you'll see that it wont work. Also if i try to change the bootstrap columns to position: static, same thing and nothing happens.

Comment: You're using `transform-style: preserve-3d` for the card, that makes the static positioning not to work. Try controlling the position in the `.flipped` class instead.